# Unresolved Import QtGui in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, qt, python-3.x, pyqt

I'm importing QtGui in Eclipse. 
i.e.

```
 from PyQt4 import QtGui
```

It is giving me error  Unresolved Import QtGui. I'm unable to resolve this issue. Please give me solition to this problem.

Comment: always add in question full error message (Traceback). There can be more usefull information.

Comment: Unresolved import QtGui
Unused import QtGui

Comment: I repeat: always add **in question** *FULL* error message (Traceback). There can be more usefull information.

Comment: Make sure pyqt4 is installed

Answer (score 2):

Go to your Python x.x Folder in your C:\ and then go to `Lib\site-packages` then delete your PyQt Folder if there is any, then Download PyQt4 here:

1. Windows [Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/PyQt-win-gpl-4.11.4.zip)
2. Mac [Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/PyQt-mac-gpl-4.11.4.tar.gz)
3. Linux [Link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pyqt/files/PyQt4/PyQt-4.11.4/PyQt-x11-gpl-4.11.4.tar.gz)

Then Go a head and Start Building Awesome GUI!!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you installed PyQt4 before attemping to import it.

Download PyQT4 from [here](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download).